# Postgres Serializable/Bytea Retrieval

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a table column type bytea. It is populated using hibernate and a field of type Serializable. Any ideas how I would be able to retrieve the values outside hibernate in a simple java standalone program? The values are of type string, double or integer.

the database is UTF8

```
while(res.next()){
    byte[] byteArr = res.getBytes("value");
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInput.html, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: Thanks @Craig for your links, they pointed me in the right direction:

  while (res.next()) {
   byte[] byteArr = ddResults.getBytes("value");
   ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
   Serializable val = (Serializable) ois.readObject();
   System.out.println(val);
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
while (res.next()) {
    byte[] byteArr = res.getBytes("value");
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    Serializable val = (Serializable) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(val);
}
```